# Checking the exit code of a CLI in a test

Tags: python, pytest, exit-code

I am writing automated tests for a command line tool.  Essentially, I want to invoke the CLI with various options and test the exit code and/or output.

My test looks like this:

```
from mymodule.cli_tool import main

def test_args(capfd):
    with pytest.raises(SystemExit) as e:
        main(args=['--junk_option'])
    # check the exit code to make sure it is non-zero
    ???
```

How do I check the exit code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check `value.code`, like this:

```
assert e.value.code != 0
```