# What type of error argparse.ArgumentParser raises for missing required args

Tags: python, error-handling, argparse

I need to ensure an error is raised using pytest given the following:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-x', required=True)
parser.parse_args()
```

which without passing something to `-x` flag when called, will result in:

```
usage: my_script.py [-h] -x X
my_script.py: error: the following arguments are required: -x
```

Which if I intentionally tried to create an ambiguous type error, probably I won't be able to come up with a better one. I need to specify some error type to be checked like the following:

```
with pytest.raises(SomeError):
    test_condition()
```

Even wrapping things in `try` and `except` blocks won't work, and so far I tried `KeyError`, `ValueError`, `SystemError`, `SystemExit`, `argparse.ArgumentError`, `KeyError`, `Exception` ... and nothing seems to work.

Comment: I don't think will be able to catch the exception directly from the output of your 'argparse implementation', since it does not thrown an exception, instead it display a human readable message into the console. Therefore I believe you gonna have to get the output and raise an exception yourself, thus later on you'll be able to catch it using your with ' pytest.raises ' implementation

Comment: why simplify things while we can make it impossibly challenging as usual.

Comment: If this was handled via an exception, you’d get a back trace with it too, which surely isn’t what you want in a CLI. It’s probably printing the message and then exits. So, if anything, a system-exit exception may be the only thing you can catch.

Comment: Nothing catches it, not even a bare except. I know this may be intended, I just don't get why it shouldn't be an exception though and what makes it any different than  `print('I am an error'); exit(1)`

Comment: Look in the `argparse.py` file.  Errors like this go through `parser.error` and `parser.exit`.  This does a `sys.exit`. Other [argparse] SO questions have discussed testing.

Comment: In fact I did but it leads nowhere.

Comment: Related questions suggest `SystemExit`

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/30256332

Answer (score 3):

As default argparse doesn't throw an exception, but exit when an error occur. Since python 3.9, there is an [`exit_on_error`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#exit-on-error) argument, but it only raise exception when type checking fail. It still [exit on unknown argument](https://bugs.python.org/issue41255).

A better approach to not alter the behavior of the program, is to check the call to `sys.exit`:

```py
>>> import argparse, mock
>>> parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
>>> with mock.patch("sys.exit") as m:
...     parser.parse_args(("bad", "argument"))
...     print("sys.exit call count: %d" % m.call_count)
... 
usage: [-h]
: error: unrecognized arguments: bad argument
Namespace()
sys.exit call count: 1
```

Comment: Thanks, I was able to pass the tests that used to fail by passing `SystemExit` to `pytest.raises()` with other modifications. Your answer is very useful though which is another way of testing the same condition.